# limit first person camera's pitch rotation c++ ue4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So, I'm trying to limit how much the camera can look up and down in my first person game and I wasn't able to get a good result so far. I made a very basic method for looking up and down (I'm still a noob in c++). What should I add to my code ?

```
void AYT_Character::LookUpAtRate(float value)
{
   AddControllerPitchInput(value * BaseLookUpAtRate* GetWorld()->GetDeltaSeconds());
}
```

any help will be appreciated, I want to do this in c++ and avoid blueprints as much as possible for now.

Comment: Have you tried using a clamp?

Comment: I did, I'm not sure If I did it the right way but it caused the camera to constantly go up and down by itself.
I made a float variable inside the method and wrote var = FMath::clamp(value, min, max) and then I put the var instead of value that is passed into the method

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Answer (score 2):

From a Character class you can set it in BeginPlay() not the constructor:

```
APlayerController* PlayerController = Cast<APlayerController>(Controller);
if (PlayerController)
{
    if (PlayerController->PlayerCameraManager)
    {
        PlayerController->PlayerCameraManager->ViewPitchMin = 45.0; // Use whatever values you want
        PlayerController->PlayerCameraManager->ViewPitchMax = 100.0;
    }
}
```

I removed CastToPlayerController answer since it is becoming deprecated.

Comment: I should write this inside the ACharacter class ? also, I've seen PlayerCameraManager online somewhere but right now I just made my own new camera with default empty settings.

Comment: But how is the player camera manager connected to my default camera ? Sorry, I'm just lost here. I already wrote this in my custom character class constructor:

PlayerCameraMan = CreateDefaultSubobject<APlayerCameraManager>(TEXT("PlayerCameraMan"));
PlayerCameraMan->ViewPitchMax;
PlayerCameraMan->ViewPitchMin;


How is this going to connect to my default camera component which I already set up ?

Comment: this is how my camera is set without the player camera manager stuff:
SpringArmComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArmComp"));
SpringArmComp->AttachToComponent(GetMesh(),
FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale,"Head");
CameraComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent(TEXT("CameraComp"));
CameraComp-> SetupAttachment(SpringArmComp);

Comment: Updated to show proper code since CastToPlayerController is becoming deprecated.